# How can i have a paypal return_url with post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, shopping-cart, checkout, cart

I have a shopping cart with paypal but I need back to create order method with the url order_url but paypal back with get and I need a post

Comment: There is not enough information in this post, and so I've voted it to be closed. Please show us the code that you have tried and explain why it didn't work. If you don't have any code, please explain the problem in greater detail than just a few short sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use return_url or cancel_url as safe hooks to create/update/destroy records in your database (e.g. for carts and products) and close the payment loop, because PayPal won't consider your payment VALID and will keep it in a pending state.

The correct way to make user's transaction VALID, is to expose the IPN_notification_url instead, which is a callback invoked by the PayPal server after it receives a payment query from your site, and the parameters you receive are in form of a POST. You may look at this https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/#protocol_and_arch to clarify the entire flow.

You can consider to use the return_url and cancel_url only to show some payment summary to the user and maybe their invoice.